# wrap images with heights in percentages inside of floated divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

Sorry to ask a really obvious question I'm sure it has a really simple answer, I just can't figure it out.

Very simply I want to place images inside of divs, where the images fill 100% of the height of the div.

CSS

```
.container{
      height:100%;
      float:left;}

img {
      height:100%;}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
       <img src="xyz.jpg" />
</div>
```

The result is as expected but with a large amount of whitespace to the right of the image (within the div) when viewed in any non-webkit browser.

In my layout I want to have many of these divs lined up (by float) in a row so its essential that the div's width shrinks to that of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/osnoz/VzrnT/

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `div` without specified height dimensions only expands enough to encompass its contents.  Without a specified width, the `div` will expand to the width of its parent.  So until you specify the width, the `div`'s width will not shrink down to the image.

Your `div` is set to `100%` height, which is in relation to **its** *container* height, **not** its contents.

You also do not need to specify `100%` on the image itself.  This will only make the image *stretch* to 100% of its container's height.  Unless, you specify a container height, this is pointless.

Comment: Sorry, didn't make thing clear, t want the image to stretch to 100% of the container's height which is 100% of the body height.

Comment: @osnoz, I think you should post a jsFiddle example.  Also, what you desire does not invalidate my answer.  You must specify a width if you don't want the div to expand horizontally.

Comment: I want the div to expand to fit the contents, I cannot specify the width as I don't know what it will be (percentage layout)

Comment: @osnoz, then what you want is not so simple without JavaScript. Div's fill their parent horizontally unless you specify a width.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood the question right, but here it goes:

```
.container { display: inline-block; height: 100%; }
.container img { height: 100%; }
```

See the example at [jsfiddle.net/erxLv/2](http://jsfiddle.net/erxLv/2/)